# Android : Get recently added media in Android Device similarly to File Manager

Tags: android, media, android-contentresolver, android-mediascanner

I am working on an application in which I have to notify user as soon as a new image, video, audio or apk is inserted by the user by any means (whether he downloads it or transfer it),similar to what File Manager application do.I don't know where to start from. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my complete code to notify user when a new media (image, audio or video) is added into the device. It might help someone.Also, I am displaying push notifications as soon as new media is added.

**EDITED** (issues resolved are below)
1.Notify user only when media is added,not deleted.

```
    public class MediaTrackerService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // images
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                true, new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
                    @Override
                    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                        super.onChange(selfChange);

                        Media media = readFromMediaStore(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                        File file = new File(media.file.getPath());
                        Date fileData = new Date(file.lastModified());

                        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - fileData.getTime() > 3000) {

                        } else {

                            if (!media.file.getPath().contains("WhatsApp")) {
                                String saved = media.file.getName();

                                // deduce bitmap before using
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                        .decodeFile(media.file.getPath());

                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(media.file),
                                        "image/*");
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                                        .getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                                                0, intent, 0);

                                Notification n = new Notification.Builder(
                                        getApplicationContext())
                                        .setStyle(
                                                new Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                                                        .bigPicture(bitmap))
                                        .setContentTitle(
                                                "New Image File For You")
                                        .setContentText("File Name :" + saved)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon_1)
                                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                        .setAutoCancel(true).build();

                                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                                notificationManager.notify(0, n);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
                    }
                });
        // audio
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                true, new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
                    @Override
                    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                        super.onChange(selfChange);
                        Media media = readFromMediaStore(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                        File file = new File(media.file.getPath());
                        Date fileData = new Date(file.lastModified());

                        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - fileData.getTime() > 3000) {

                        } else {

                            if (!media.file.getPath().contains("WhatsApp")) {

                                String saved = media.file.getName();

                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                        .decodeFile(media.file.getPath());

                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(media.file),
                                        "audio/*");
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                                        .getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                                                0, intent, 0);

                                Notification n = new Notification.Builder(
                                        getApplicationContext())
                                        .setStyle(
                                                new Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                                                        .bigPicture(null))
                                        .setContentTitle(
                                                "New audio File For You")
                                        .setContentText("File Name :" + saved)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon_1)
                                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                        .setAutoCancel(true).build();

                                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                                notificationManager.notify(0, n);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
                    }
                });
        // video
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                true, new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
                    @Override
                    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                        super.onChange(selfChange);
                        Media media = readFromMediaStore(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                        File file = new File(media.file.getPath());
                        Date fileData = new Date(file.lastModified());

                        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - fileData.getTime() > 3000) {

                        } else {
                            if (!media.file.getPath().contains("WhatsApp")) {

                                String saved = media.file.getName();

                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(media.file),
                                        "video/*");
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                                        .getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                                                0, intent, 0);

                                Notification n = new Notification.Builder(
                                        getApplicationContext())
                                        .setStyle(
                                                new Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                                                        .bigPicture(null))
                                        .setContentTitle(
                                                "New Video File For You")
                                        .setContentText("File Name :" + saved)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon_1)
                                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                        .setAutoCancel(true).build();

                                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                                notificationManager.notify(0, n);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
                        System.out
                                .println("here is the service change EXTERNAL 1 params"
                                        + " " + uri);
                    }
                });
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private Long readLastDateFromMediaStore(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,
                null, "date_added DESC");
        Long dateAdded = (long) -1;
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            dateAdded = cursor.getLong(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return dateAdded;
    }

    private Media readFromMediaStore(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,
                null, "date_added DESC");
        Media media = null;
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
            int mimeTypeColumn = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE);
            String mimeType = cursor.getString(mimeTypeColumn);
            media = new Media(new File(filePath), mimeType);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return media;
    }

    private class Media {
        private File file;

        private String type;

        public Media(File file, String type) {
            this.file = file;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public File getFile() {
            return file;
        }
    }
}
```

and don't forget to unregister your observer `onDestroy()`.

```
getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(yourObserverObject);
```

Comment: Thank you this is work perfectly. but what if I kill the app and I want result in background also?

Comment: @HarinKaklotar everthing above is done inside a service class 'MediaTrackerService' which runs in background only. Killing the app will have on effect on the result.

Comment: yes I know that. but if user kill the app and after that user add some music file to device so how can user notify ?  
and suppose we use BroadcastReceiver with service then, what is intent shoud i pass in BroadcastReceiver for get new Audio file in device ?

Comment: @HarinKaklotar what do you mean by kill the app ? You mean removing it from recent tasks ? 
Yes it will work if application is removed from the recent tasks.

Comment: Note that this code will not work on Android O and higher.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in general. Your app has no rights to spy on the behavior of other apps. If the user, through my app, downloads something to my app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), you cannot access that content (unless I choose to make it available) and you cannot find out that the content was added.

Beyond that, prior to API Level 24 (Android 7.0), there is no means for you accomplish this other than by trying to have a process running all the time. This is not good for the user, in terms of system RAM consumption and the like. Some users get very irritated when apps try to have a process run all of the time, and they may express their irritation in creative ways in the form of app store ratings.

All that being said, for publicly-accessible content (principally [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html)), the simplest solution would be to set up a `ContentObserver` to monitor the `MediaStore` `ContentProvider`. On Android 7.0+, you could use `JobScheduler` to do the same thing, with the benefit that you do not need to keep your process running to keep the `ContentObserver` observing.

Comment: thanks for your enlightment. I have achieved the desire task by using ContentObserver

Comment: Hi again, I've achieved the desired task and post the answer also but I issue  I am facing is, I only want to notify user if media is added, not deleted. This chunk of code runs in both cases.

Comment: @bhanukaushik: Sorry, but you will be notified for all changes (additions, modifications, removals). It will be up to you to somehow determine whether some media was added. This is one of the reasons why few apps try doing what you are doing.