# I want to start a service only when a new picture is clicked in android. How do I go about doing that?

Tags: android, image-capture, contentobserver

I want to start a service only when a new picture is captured from the phone camera in android. How do I go about doing that? Currently, I am running a background task that runs every 3 seconds to check if a new picture has been clicked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859816/how-to-listen-new-photos-in-android

Comment: Maybe `ContentObserver` is what you are looking for. This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/40066666/7976274

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into this

Answer (score 0):

You can have tracks for image clicks then check those tracks every 3 seconds.

```
final boolean hasClicked = false;

new View.OnClickListener() { //image onclick listener
    hasClicked = true;
}



new Timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     if ( hasClicked ) {
         // start your service
     }

}, 3000, 3000);
```

If you need to track how many times the user clicked the image before the interval you can make a counter for it. be careful about the spam clicks.

Comment: This is what I am already doing. I need to know how can i add a trigger to the camera(dcim) folder so that my service fires whenever a new image is added to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no APIs for logging and monitoring camera activity, probably for privacy and security reasons